# Attribute tag is not working in layout magento 2.2

Tags: magento2.2, page-layouts

I am facing attribute tag issues in the layout XML after upgrading to Magento-2.2. I have added the below tag in the "Layout Update XML" field of Magento cms page but it's not working. Can you please provide the supported tag for the blow

```
<attribute name="class" value="xyz-active"/>
```